# Is android-asynct-http library coupled with UI thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-async-http, android-background

I want to use this awesome library for my server request in my application to do some work on map. **My need is I want to make server request for every 2 minutes without block user interaction on the screen while server requesting process happening and in the onSuccess call back I'll do some work on the map.**
How can I use this library for my need? and **the library coupled with Android activity and fragment life cycle?**

Please refer this site for the library information.
http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Answer (score 2):

Actually that's is from the page you linked http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ . Theses callbacks are executed in the UI thread but the actual request is being processed in another thread.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        // called when request is retried
    }
});
```

In your Activity's **onStop()** you should call AsyncHttpClient's **cancelAllRequests(Context context, boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)** method to cancel all the active and pending requests.

```
client.cancelAllRequests(this, true);
```

This should ensure that the callbacks of your requests are never called and then save yourself from non trivial network usage and save yourself from IllegalStateExceptions.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your point and what will happen if a activity is destroyed?